# How to return the desired type in action creator React Typescript Redux

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I have a problem. Look at my code first:

```
export const login = (email: string, password: string) => {
    return async (dispatch: Dispatch<UserAction>) => {
        try {
            dispatch({type: UserActionTypes.FETCH_USER})
            const response = await axios.post<IUser>('http://localhost:8080/auth/signIn', {email, password})
            dispatch({type: UserActionTypes.FETCH_USER_SUCCESS, payload: response.data})
            return response.data
        }catch (e) {
            dispatch({
                type: UserActionTypes.FETCH_USER_ERROR,
                payload: 'Произошла ошибка при загрузке пользователя'
            })
        }
    }
}
```

It's my action creator, where i authentificate user.

```
        let principal = await login(email.value, password.value)
        console.log(principal)
```

Here I try to get the response, i return in action creator, i get not what i need and i can't get fields i need.
[image]

But what i see in console `console.log(principal)`: this is object, i needed, but i can't get his fields:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `useDispatch` hook. https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#usedispatch

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();
```

And then dispatch the login action.

```
dispatch(login(email.value, password.value));
```

also you do not need to await when you dispatch an action.

Comment: I use custom hook useUserActions:                                                                                 
`import * as UserActionCreators from "../../redux/action_creators/user"

export const useUserActions = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch()

    return bindActionCreators(UserActionCreators, dispatch)
}`  My question is about returning value, where i can't get fields, but in console you can see on the image, that i get desired object

Comment: since you are using thunk, you do not return from a thunk function. This is not the correct way to do it. you should get the state from redux using `useSelector` hook.

Comment: there is a problem with this approach, because i set user, which i get from backend authorization and check user null or not, and when i first time put the button, user is null, when i put second time, user is not null, but i neet that it work from the first time.

Comment: you need to use `useEffect` hook. It should work.